# Can't loop all controls in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# form with some types of controls, i throught this code for loop all `Labels` and re-parent:

```
private void MakeAllLabelTrans(Control frm, Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in frm.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is Label)
        {
            ctl.Parent = parent;
            // ctl.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
        else if (ctl.HasChildren)
        {
            MakeAllLabelTrans(ctl, parent);
        }
    }
}
```

and call as: `MakeAllLabelTrans(this, picBackground);` in Form_Load event, but some label was missed (i have puted a messagebox in the loop body - it really not in the loop), but i don't know why?

Comment: you might want to remove the `else` from the `else if` condition - just in case you somehow end up with a label that has children

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're changing the collection while enumerating it. This leads to some items being skipped.

You should rewrite this to first build a list of controls that will need to be reparented, and then reparent them in a second pass.

Comment: Ok, it work well, thanks, but it seem not enought time to accept ;)

Comment: Can you please elaborate what can be an issue regarding the code provided by OP?

Comment: @FSX The issue is changing a collection while enumerating it. Not sure how to elaborate.

Comment: @FSX: Well, the actual issue (that is not so obvious) is that changing the `Parent` property of a `Control` to a different parent implicitly **removes** that control from the previous `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the collection on which you are iterating.

```
private static IEnumerable<Labels> FindAllLabels(Control container)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in container.Controls)
    {
        var lbl = ctl as Label;
        if (lbl != null)
        {
            yield return ctl;
        }
        else if (ctl.HasChildren)
        {
            foreach (var innerResult in FindAllLabels(ctl))
                yield return innerResult;
        }
    }
}

// now call the method like this if you want to change a property on the label
foreach (var label in FindAllLabels(theForm))
    label.BackgroundColor = Color.White;

// or like this (note the .ToList()) if you want to move the labels around:
foreach (var label in FindAllLabels(theForm).ToList())
    label.Parent = someOtherControl;
```

Comment: This does not work, the original collection is still updated while looping, and causes the same issue.